# Unit test a method consist of web controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, mstest

Asp.net web application, that having samplepage.aspx and samplepage.aspx.cs file. For code coverage, Need to cover all methods in codebehind. Writing unit test cases in MStest, is it possible to unit test `Reset()` method that contains web page controls `txtName.Text = string.Empty;`  Kindly suggest to solve this issue.

```
protected override void Reset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
         Reset();
   }
    
   public void Reset()
   {
       txtName.Text = string.Empty;
   }
```

Comment: You should exclude your code-behind files from code coverage. They are not testable.

Comment: Have excluded aspx files, but code-behind files are not excluded. So trying to cover all methods. Thanks for your immediate response

Comment: Why would you want to test a method that have no logic in it?

Comment: @Zohar Peled, I have given a sample method and event, in some other methods there is logic. Need to test those methods(logics). And our main motive is to increase code coverage.